# What is this abandoned aircraft in Thailand?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

A friend found an old photo of himself and an abandoned aircraft in Thailand. Can you identify the aircraft?

Answer (score 18):

### [Curtiss C-46 Commando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_C-46_Commando)

First flight was 26 March 1940. 3,181 were built. The [one you have](http://www.warbirdregistry.org/c46registry/c46-4478738.html) was stored at Don Muang, and ended up in Chonburi, Thailand.

Identifying features are the nose light, the now faded blue/gray cheatline that turns upward behind the cockpit windows, the black antenna under the cockpit, and the white paint under the nose that is gone from the belly:

[image]
([airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled/Curtiss-C-46F-Commando-CW-20B-4/1113608))

Matching engine:

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Curtiss_C-46_Commando_China_Doll_(77022594).jpg))

Matching front view:

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Reeve_Aleutian_Curtiss_C-46_2N.jpg))

Comment: WOW you are awesome!!! Thank you!